# Chatter Free users: Automatic login link works, but username/password login does not

Tags: chatter, sandbox, user-management, login-errors, user-admin

I'm trying to setup some "Chatter Free" license type users in a sandbox. (These are new test users not users copied from production.)

The long automatic login URL in the initial (and any "Reset Password") password confirmation emails works and allows a new password to be specified and then routes through to normal access to the org.

But when I then logout and try to login via https://test.salesforce.com/ using the username and the new password the generic "Your login attempt has failed..." message is displayed. There is no record of these failed attempts in the "Login History" either.

(A typo in the username or password is the obvious explanation but as well as carefully repeating the process I've reviewed this with one colleague and left another colleague to try it independently, all with the same result.)

Using the sandbox name as a suffix on the username doesn't help.

So I feel like I'm missing something obvious here perhaps related to this being a sandbox or perhaps relating to the license type. Any help appreciated.

Comment: I just created a chatter free user and I cannot log in via test.salesforce.com or by using url parameters at all. I am seeing the same thing as you. A password reset gets me in...I am testing on CS10

Comment: @Eric Thanks for giving it a go. As you are seeing it too I've just created a case; maybe this is an unpublished "known issue". As the support process is often slow, if anyone has insight please post an answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce support have come back with this work-around that works:

1. Create a Chatter Free user.
2. User will be able to login using the initial login link.
3. User logs out.
4. The next time user tries to login, please ask them to login using instance_name.salesforce.com instead of test.salesforce.com. For example, the login URL for the users of UAT sandbox might be cs8.salesforce.com.
5. User will be able to login successfully from now without any issues.

I've asked them if the problem will be fixed (as getting large numbers of users to follow the above process correctly will be hard) but doubt that it will get priority.

**PS** Support says "even though we do not have an ETA on this, we are currently working on a fix for this".